# How to redirect to maintain page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to redirect to the maintains page. Can anyone let me know how can we redirect it from admin panel?

Comment: Please confirm your Magento version. You have mentioned magento-1.9 and magento2 both.

Comment: I'm using magento 2.2.3

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible from admin panel (correct me if I'm wrong), however, you can enable the maintenance mode by creating a `.maintenance.flag` file in **var/pub**; if you have FTP access.

If you want to exclude some IP's, you need to create a file called `.maintenance.ip` with a list of IP's that can be except from maintenance mode.

You can also set the maintenance mode using the following command:

> magento maintenance:enable

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html